# Bad value ... for attribute rel on element a: The string ... is not a registered keyword

Tags: html, plugins, rel

I am trying to debug my website but i don't know how to get rid of these errors.

Bad value lightbox[322] for attribute rel on element a: The string lightbox[322] is not a registered keyword. I have about 45 of these errors all pretty much the same.

HTML

```
<div class="large-3 columns"><a href="http://timberlife.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/BUITENHUIS-1.11.jpg" rel="lightbox[318]" title="BUITENHUIS I 40 m2" class="cboxElement" data-target="flare">
<img class="aligncenter wp-image-705 size-medium" src="http://timberlife.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/BUITENHUIS-1.11-200x300.jpg" alt="BUITENHUIS 1.1" width="200" height="300"><br>
```

I am using a plugin to use lightbox on my images.
I'm having the same problem where U use a plugin for a scroll effect.

Bad value m_PageScroll2id for attribute rel on element a: The string m_pagescroll2id is not a registered keyword.

Many thanks

Daan

Answer (score 3):

In HTML5, the `rel` attribute can only have link types as value that are

- [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#linkTypes) or
- [registered in the Microformats wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions).

You should probably look for better plugins. Good plugins would let you use valid attributes, like [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).